# How to name output zip without version number in packaging with setuptools

Tags: setuptools

Hi I am packaging a module with setuptools. Here is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup( 
    name='my_package',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires = ['pymongo'],
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner','flake8'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    test_suite="tests"
)
```

After I run `python setup.py sdist --format=zip` the output zip file is created in dist folder. So far so good. But output file automatically named `my_package-0.0.0.zip`. I want it to be named just `my_package.zip`. How can I do that with setuptools?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's non-standard and breaks the assumptions made by other related tooling (eg pip).

Comment: I'am going to use this custom package for offline installation and other things and there are some selection processes go with name.

Comment: I would just let _setuptools_ do what it does, then rename the file some other way afterwards. Doing it from within `setup.py` would be unnecessarily complicated and against its philosophy.